# how to filter data array_agg from postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have view at postgres db from this query

```
SELECT order_product.order_id,
  array_agg(order_product.product_id) AS itemset 
FROM order_product
GROUP BY order_product.order_id
ORDER BY order_product.order_id;
```

and this is the structure look like:

[image]

And the question is, how can U filter data at (itemset) just show where the value is more than 1 (example: don't show = `{8}`, just show the value when containing 2 data or more like this = `{8,10}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `having()` clause:

```
SELECT op.order_id,
       array_agg(op.product_id) AS itemset 
FROM order_product op
GROUP BY op.order_id
HAVING count(*) > 1 --<< here
ORDER BY op.order_id;
```

Comment: thank you that solved my problem, very grateful for your answer